# Wordpress Metabox

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I am hoping one of your can help clean up this code a bit. What I am doing is working properly but I am sure there is a more efficient approach. I am creating a theme in Wordpress and inside of a custom post type I am creating some meta options. I am using an `<ul>` to display a list of options the author can include. Now I am displaying the list of options using this format:

```
<ul>
    <?php if(isset($meta['tour_detail1'][0])) { 
        echo "<li>{$meta['tour_detail1'][0]}</li>";
    } ?>
    <?php if(isset($meta['tour_detail2'][0])) { 
        echo "<li>{$meta['tour_detail2'][0]}</li>";
    } ?>
    <?php if(isset($meta['tour_detail3'][0])) { 
        echo "<li>{$meta['tour_detail3'][0]}</li>";
    } ?>
</ul>
```

In this example I am only using 3 options but in the theme I currently am using 5. I am still new to php but I am guessing a foreach loop would fit great here? I am saving each option as its own variable but feel I could possible save it to an array? I have looked around the internet but I could not find much on what I am looking for. I apologize if this question seems everywhere but I am not sure on how to word it.

Comment: Can you show us how you getting `$meta` variable ? Are you using `get_post_meta` function?

Comment: Yes, I am using this `$tour_detail1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tour_detail1', true);`

Comment: Can you try `$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );` ? And check whether you able to pull all post meta at once.